In-Memory database seems to be persisting data
I have this NUnit test:
using System.Data.SQLite;

    [Test]
    public async Task InMemoryTest()
    {
        using var connection = new SQLiteConnection(
            "Data Source=file:abc?mode=memory&cache=shared;"
        );
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (MyColumn int);";
        _ = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        await connection.CloseAsync();
    }

It just creates a table in an in-memory database. When I run the test the first time, it passes. When I run it the second time (in another process), it fails saying that the table is already created.
What is very strange is that I can't find any persisted DB file on disk. Why does the table seem to be persisted between test runs?
Edit: The same issue occurs with this connection string:
Data Source=abc;mode=memory;cache=shared;

The connection string seems weird. Is there a reason you're giving a filename at all, and then try to "cancel" that using the mode? I'd suspect the file abc is created in whatever the CWD of the test-process is (outside your view), and the mode being ignored. See the docs on how to create an in-memory db connection.

true, but that's how SQLite docs say to open it. The MS docs say to use "Data Source=InMemorySample;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared". The other reason is the 1st process might be keeping the DB open when the 2nd calls it. Is there garbage collection before it gets cleaned up?

You are using System.Data.SQLite. Everywhere on the Internet are provided connection strings for another provider: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, but they differ! Download the most complete documentation as a CHM file from here.

The connection string parameters must be separated by a semicolon. There are no mode and cache parameters in the documentation.

So either use the correct documentation, or switch to another provider.

@AlexanderPetrov yes but Microsoft.Data.SQLite doesn’t support named in-memory databases.
